# Nested if/else, else being executed when it should't?

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with a nested if/else statement.. The else statement above partial match executes even when the if statement evaluates true.. I cannot see why that would happen.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def search():
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('search_form.html') # TODO ADD THIS TEMPLATE
elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = 'Search Form'
    searchInput = request.form['search']
    if len(searchInput) < 3:
        errStr = 'The search term you entered is to short. Searches must have 4 characters.'
        msg = [form, errStr]
        return error(msg)
    else:
        exactMatch = Clients.query.filter(or_(Clients.cellNum==searchInput,
                                          Clients.homeNum==searchInput,
                                          Clients.otherNum==searchInput)).first()
        print(exactMatch.firstName)
        print(bool(exactMatch))
        if exactMatch is True:
            clientID = exactMatch.id
            print(clientID)
        else:
            partialSearch = Clients.query.filter(or_(Clients.cellNum.like("%{}%".format(searchInput)),
                                         Clients.homeNum.like("%{}%".format(searchInput)),
                                         Clients.otherNum.like("%{}%".format(searchInput)),
                                         Clients.lastName.like("%{}%".format(searchInput)),
                                         Clients.firstName.like("%{}%".format(searchInput)))).all()
            return render_template('display_search.html', results=partialSearch)
```

Comment: `is` tests for identity. It checks if both objects are the same, and obviously the return of `filter` does not return the object `True`. You want to use the `==` operator, or in this case, just completely omit it and just write `if exactMatch:`

Answer (score 4):

`bool(exactMatch)` being `True` does not imply that `exactMatch` is strictly `True`.

Objects in Python may be *truthy* and *falsy* in boolean context even if they are not booleans.

For example:

```
bool("")  # False
"" is False  # False
bool("abc")  # True
"abc" is True  # False
```

For common Python idiom you skip identity check. For example:

```
if exactMatch:
    do_something()
    # executes if exactMatch is thruthy in boolean context, including:
    # True, non-empty sequences, non-empty strings and almost all custom user classes
else:
    do_other_thing()
    # executes if exactMatch is falsy in boolean context, including:
    # False, None, empty sequences etc.
```